# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent store - happens occasionally

Tags: sqlite, core-data, ios7

I have been using core data in my project with database.sqlite datastore file in my documents directory. My application allows to export this sqlite file as a backup to later restore. Backup works fine.

I have a backup file exported from an iOS6 device. I want to import this backup file into my app. I have the file as a mail attachment, I use open-in to open it with the app. Works fine in ios6 or earlier. I have tried to import the same file several times and it works nicely.

I have recently changed my database schema to a new version where automatic migration is well capable to switch to the new database. If my device is in iOS6, I can import the old database file or any file exported now. I can do it any number of times.

Now, if you I change my device to iOS7, I can import recently exported file any number of times. But if I try to import the old file exported earlier I can import once. The app works fine. Then I try to import it again, now it fails from the 2nd try onwards. Gives error as mentioned in the title. Only in iOS7 and only from 2nd consecutive tries.

I am using scarybug docs to unzip to imported file. Then I replace the existing sqlite database file with the imported one. Works every time in iOS6, work first time in iOS7, but fails in iOS7 from 2nd tries.

Before the import is performed all changes a committed/saved, managed object context reset-ed and persistent store coordinator reset-ed. The new file takes place of the old one and it has been working for so long. The problem only found in iOS7 from 2nd try with the same file exported from iOS6

Any help & queries will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Added this dictionary -

```
NSMutableDictionary *pragmaOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"NORMAL" forKey:@"locking_mode"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"DELETE" forKey:@"journal_mode"];
```

to the options dictionary -

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                         pragmaOptions, NSSQLitePragmasOption, nil];
```

Used to create my persistentStoreCoordinator. And that fixed my problem.